# quiero que el combo box me guarde el codigo de un campo?

Tags: java, combobox

Estoy realizando un proyecto personal, tengo dos tablas:

```
|---------|
|Area     |
|---------|
|Cod_Area   |
|Nomb_Area|
|Ubicacion|
|---------|

|---------|
|Empleados|
|---------|
|DNI      |
|Nombre   |
|Apellido |
|Cod_Area     |
|Celular  |
|Cargo    |
|---------|
```

Este ultimo esta en un **JFrame** el campo `Area` de mi `tblEmpleados` es un *Combo Box*, cuando registro un empleado, en el *Combo Box* area me sale el nombre del area pero yo quiero que guarde el codigo del area en la **BD** y no el nombre, el nombre del area solo que aparezca a la hora de registrar un empleado en el **JFrame**.
Me sale este error

> Error de conversión al convertir el valor nvarchar 'Contabilidad' al
>   tipo de datos int

Este es el código para traer datos de una tabla de apoyo hacia un *Combo Box*:

```
Statement Sent = cn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = Sent.executeQuery("SELECT*FROM Area");
while(rs.next()){
this.ComboArea.addItem(rs.getString("Nomb_Area"));
```

Este me guarda datos:

```
PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("insert into Empleados values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
pst.setString(1, txtDNI.getText().trim());
pst.setString(2, txtNombres.getText().trim());
pst.setString(3, txtApellidos.getText().trim());
pst.setString(4,ComboArea.getSelectedItem().toString());
pst.setString(5, txtCelular.getText().trim());
pst.setString(6, ComboCargo.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

Comment: En tu código intentas obtener la columna Nomb_Area pero esa columna no está en tus tablas, quizá sea eso.

Answer (score 1):

recuerda que el JComboBox permite guardar objetos, por lo tanto puedes tener una lista de objetos de tipo area y dentro de la clase area puedes guardar tanto el código como el nombre, lo que quieras mostrar al usuario lo pones en el método toString de esa clase y cuando quieras insertar en la base de datos del comboBox obtienes el objeto `ComboArea.getSelectedItem()`, lo casteas a la clase Area y de ese objeto sacas el codigo, algo asi `((Area)ComboArea.getSelectedItem()).getCodigo()`.